# Embedded video on fullscreen is not on top of the site

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video, fullscreen

Okay, this is a strange one. When the embedded video is clicked (on Chrome) to be seen on **fullscreen**, it's moved on the right because of the sidebar. On Firefox, it's as it should -the video is correctly stretched over the whole site. However, there is something that doesn't allow **Chrome** to do that.

Okay, I managed to find that this is connected with the `animation-fill-mode`. And I'm afraid that this is duplicate of [HTML5 video won't maximize beyond container dimensions in native full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785859/html5-video-wont-maximize-beyond-container-dimensions-in-native-full-screen-mod=)